# Convert Lat/Long to UTM specifying which zone to use (C++)

Tags: c++, utm

I need to convert Latitude/Longitude coordinates into UTM, in C++, specifying which zone to use.

I am working with locations that fall in two zones, and would like to project them all into one zone - since they are not too far from the border, I am hoping the error introduced by doing so won't be too much.

So far I had been using Chuck Gantz's library, which converts LL to UTM, but it does not support conversion from LL to UTM specifying which zone to use.

Comment: And how is C++ connected with this pure-algorithmic problem?

Comment: Because I'm developing in C++ and need a library in that langugage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MSP GEOTRANS](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/geotrans/) (The UTM class receives a UTM zone override parameter)

or [GeographicLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geographiclib/) (Use the SetAltZone method).