# How to resolve a 'Received NULL pointer' ArgumentOutOfRangeException for OSGeo.OGR.Geometry.TransformTo?

Tags: gdal, c#, coordinate-system, fwtools

I am attempting to project a geometry using the GDAL c# bindings and I'm getting a ArgumentOutOfRangeException ('Received NULL pointer') exception on the Transform methods of Geometry. I'm also getting the same exception when attempting to project a point using a `OSGeo.OSR.CoordinateTransformation` (e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/61574/31).

I am using the DLL in FWTools 2.4.7\csharp.

Has anyone seen this before and know what the fix is?

Here's a test that creates the exception for me:

```
        [TestMethod()]
        public void TransformPolygonReturnGeoJSON()
        {            
            string jsonLambert = string.Empty;
            string projectedJson = string.Empty;

            string wkt = "POLYGON ((1831321.945291 412165.262452,1831324.478486 412152.596478,1831312.445811 412108.265569,1831298.513239 412108.265569,1831287.747162 412108.265569,1831275.714486 412102.565881,1831271.914694 412100.032686,1831266.215006 412098.766089,1831253.549032 412188.694503,1831321.945291 412165.262452))";
            int srid = 102009;

            int outputSRID = 26918;

            string sridWKT  = string.Format("EPSG:{0}", srid);

            string outsridWKT = string.Format("EPSG:{0}", outputSRID);

            var g = Geometry.CreateFromWkt(wkt);

            var sr = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(sridWKT);

            g.AssignSpatialReference(sr);

            jsonLambert = g.ExportToJson();

            Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonLambert));

            var outSR = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(outsridWKT);

            try
            {
                var result = g.TransformTo(outSR); // <--- Exception occurs here

                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("result={0}", result));

                projectedJson = g.ExportToJson();

                Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(projectedJson));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the "EPSG: {0]" format doesn't work with the Transform methods.

However, I (*actually, credit goes to a co-worker of mine*) was able to get the Transforms working with a `PROJCS` spatial reference definition. And I was also able to get it working with the `SpatialReference.ImportFromEPSG`.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void TransformPolygonPROJCSReturnGeoJSON()
{
    string jsonLambert = string.Empty;
    string projectedJson = string.Empty;

    string wkt = "POLYGON ((1831321.945291 412165.262452,1831324.478486 412152.596478,1831312.445811 412108.265569,1831298.513239 412108.265569,1831287.747162 412108.265569,1831275.714486 412102.565881,1831271.914694 412100.032686,1831266.215006 412098.766089,1831253.549032 412188.694503,1831321.945291 412165.262452))";

    int srid = 102009;

    int outputSRID = 26918;

    // string sridWKT  = string.Format("EPSG:{0}", srid);
    string sridWKT = "PROJCS[\"North_America_Lambert_Conformal_Conic\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"North_American_Datum_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-96],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",20],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",60],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",40],UNIT[\"Meter\",1],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"102009\"]]";


    //string outsridWKT = string.Format("EPSG:{0}", outputSRID);

    string outsridWKT = "PROJCS[\"NAD83/UTMzone18N\",GEOGCS[\"NAD83\",DATUM[\"North_American_Datum_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS1980\",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7019\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6269\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4269\"]],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-75],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"26918\"],AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH]]";


    var g = Geometry.CreateFromWkt(wkt);

    var sr = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(sridWKT);

    g.AssignSpatialReference(sr);

    jsonLambert = g.ExportToJson();

    Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonLambert));

    var outSR = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(outsridWKT);

    try
    {
        var result = g.TransformTo(outSR); 

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("result={0}", result));

        projectedJson = g.ExportToJson();

        Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(projectedJson));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);

        throw;
    }
}

[TestMethod()]
public void TransformPolygonImportEPSGReturnGeoJSON()
{
    string jsonLambert = string.Empty;
    string projectedJson = string.Empty;

    string wkt = "POLYGON ((1831321.945291 412165.262452,1831324.478486 412152.596478,1831312.445811 412108.265569,1831298.513239 412108.265569,1831287.747162 412108.265569,1831275.714486 412102.565881,1831271.914694 412100.032686,1831266.215006 412098.766089,1831253.549032 412188.694503,1831321.945291 412165.262452))";

    int srid = 102009;

    int outputSRID = 26918;

    var g = Geometry.CreateFromWkt(wkt);

    var sr = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(string.Empty);
    sr.ImportFromEPSG(srid);           

    g.AssignSpatialReference(sr);

    jsonLambert = g.ExportToJson();

    Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonLambert));

    var outSR = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(string.Empty);
    outSR.ImportFromEPSG(outputSRID);

    try
    {
        var result = g.TransformTo(outSR); 

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("result={0}", result));

        projectedJson = g.ExportToJson();

        Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(projectedJson));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);

        throw;
    }
}
```