# How to convert lat long to UTM

Tags: c++, utm

I want to convert two double (`double longitude_wgs84_radians, double altitude_wgs84_meters`) which I get from a function.

The coordinates looks like

```
latitude_wgs84_radians: 0.924593
longitude_wgs84_radians: 0.176054
```

How can I convert them into UTM in C++? A code example or documentation would be nice.

I tried the example code from [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/classGeographicLib_1_1UTMUPS.html)  1.49

```
// Example of using the GeographicLib::UTMUPS class
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <GeographicLib/UTMUPS.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace GeographicLib;
int main() {
  try {
    // See also example-GeoCoords.cpp
    {
      // Sample forward calculation
      double lat = 33.3, lon = 44.4; // Baghdad
      int zone;
      bool northp;
      double x, y;
      UTMUPS::Forward(lat, lon, zone, northp, x, y);
      string zonestr = UTMUPS::EncodeZone(zone, northp);
      cout << fixed << setprecision(2)
           << zonestr << " " << x << " " << y << "\n";
    }
    {
      // Sample reverse calculation
      string zonestr = "38n";
      int zone;
      bool northp;
      UTMUPS::DecodeZone(zonestr, zone, northp);
      double x = 444e3, y = 3688e3;
      double lat, lon;
      UTMUPS::Reverse(zone, northp, x, y, lat, lon);
      cout << lat << " " << lon << "\n";
    }
  }
  catch (const exception& e) {
    cerr << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
}
```

but if Im trying to compile it, I get 3. errors.

```
undefined reference to `GeographicLib::UTMUPS::EncodeZone(int, bool, bool)'
undefined reference to `GeographicLib::UTMUPS::Forward(double, double, int&, bool&, double&, double&, double&, double&, int, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Convert Lat/Long to UTM specifying which zone to use (C++)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27617/convert-lat-long-to-utm-specifying-which-zone-to-use-c)

Comment: If you are using R, you need to use a function spTransform from the sp package: spTransform (x, "mention coordinate system in proj4s format")

Comment: @VijayRamesh Im sorry, what do you mean with R? Its my first experience with geographic systems.

Comment: Yes, geograpiclib   https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/

Comment: @GBG just tried to use the example, but this is not working.

Comment: What error or result are you getting?

Comment: @mkennedy just edit my question and implement the code and error

Comment: For both methods you're not passing enough parameters.

Comment: @mkennedy I know, but the code is from an example and I dont understand, what should this parametrs have.

Comment: I think that example is out-of-date. Look lower for the function/method. It has a short example giving more parameters.